# SnapBack SDK - Microphone sensor crashes

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions, audiorecord, snapback

I'm playing with the `Snapback SDK`.
When starting a `WaveGestureHandler` with microphone driven adapters (`Snap`, `Blow`) I get this error:

```
AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

  FATAL EXCEPTION: BlowDetector
Process: com.mypackage.app, PID: 27926
java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
```

How do I initialize this `AudioRecord`? I've looked at the [provided examples](https://github.com/SnapbackLabs/android-sdk-samples) but I can't find where to do it.

I'm testing on a Nexus 5 with Android L.

Answer (score 1):

The adapters which use microphone require to write some temporary data on your device, thus you have to add permissions to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This will fix the issue.

Bye

Comment: I'll need to try this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your microphone is locked by other app, like system app which uses voice commands (e.g. S voice for Samsung devices)?

Andorid L is a preview and the SDK has been compiled and tested until the API-20 (4.4W). In next days we will start to test our SDK in that environment.
Do you are compiling your app with Android L? Please, could you post your code?

Anyway, you could take a look at http://developer.snapback.io/tutorial.html where you'll can find a simple explanation of how to create an app with Snapback SDK.
I'm gonna try to explain here how to use the SDK features.
You should do something like this:

```
public class YourMainActivity extends Activity implements WaveGestureListener
```

In your onCreate():

```
waveGestureHandler = new WaveGestureHandler();
blowSensorAdapter = new BlowSensorAdapter(waveGestureHandler, this);
waveGestureHandler.setSensorAdapters(blowSensorAdapter);
waveGestureHandler.register(this);
waveGestureHandler.start();
```

and override the onEvent() method:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(WaveGestureEvent event)
{
    //print something
    Log.d("", "" + event);
}
```

Keep us posted.

Bye

Comment: I'm using this code. TargetSdk is 21, this might be the problem. Thanks for the quick answer.